# Websocket request-response sampler returning response body h

Tags: websocket, jmeter, performance-testing

Im sending some data with the request,but the response is just h
[image]
[image]

on sending the same request via the browser there should be a response message
[image]

And on the app i can confirm that the action is getting executed(in the app its a request for a bet placement,and i can see the bet placed with the amount i placed on jmeter)

- why cant i see the response message on jmeter using the request-response sampler?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it worth [enabling debug logging for WebSocket Samplers plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging), it can be done by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="eu.luminis" level="debug" />
```

this way you will see what's going on under the hood in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), i.e. how connections are being opened and closed, request and response data, headers, etc. and will be able to compare it with the browser's ones.

Perhaps it's better to use an external sniffer tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) as this way you will be able to compare frame by frame and spot the differences easier.

Given you configure JMeter to send the same request that browser does you will get the same response.

Answer (score 0):

Info from dev is that,These are STOMP heartbeat pings messages (STOMP is the way how websockets are implemented in our app) they are autogenerated by server and are only needed to keep connection open, the main issue i was having was I hadnt properly parametised the subscribe request before the send request